# Google Chrome Bug with CSS Padding style applying to empty cells

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, stylesheet, padding

I have a problem only in Google Chrome (Firefox, IE, Netscape, Safari and Opera are Okay) where a padding property which should be applied to text in a cell, is being applied to all empty cells aswell. It's easy to solve by adding more specific styles to my affected perimeter cells and using different styles, but that uses a lot of extra code and something which I try to save on. Is there possible way to get my CSS to pass over empty cells in the table it applies to?

```
#regFormTable{ padding:8px 30px 0px; }
```

Is the style affecting it.

Edit: The commas were an accident in typing the class on here (I'm using to submitting parameters syntax)

Comment: I've updated my answer with your new parameters :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think Google Chrome have a different default for the [`empty-cells`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_empty-cells.asp) css property. you should try to do :

```
#regFormTable{ padding:8px 30px 0px; empty-cells: hide; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have commas in there:

```
#regFormTable { padding: 8px 30px 0px; }
```

Also, I usually use either 2 or 4 values - it's just easier to understand!